# Hotwire Turbo in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I wish to use Hotwire Turbo in my WP app.

I'm including it like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script('Turbo', 'https://unpkg.com/@hotwired/turbo@7.3.0/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js', array(), '7.3.0', false);
```

The above line is inside a function that gets called below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

and ensuring it's getting treated as a module with:

```
function set_scripts_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'Turbo' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="module" src="'. $src .'"></script>';
    }
    return $tag;
}
```

But i'm getting this error:

> application.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: Turbo is not defined
> at application.js:29:1

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'set_scripts_type_attribute', 10, 3 );

Comment: Are you calling the `wp_enqueue_script` inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` is inside a function which I am calling as the callback of `wp_enqueue_scripts`.   I'll update my OP

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you are not setting any dependencies for the script. This means that the script will not be able to find the other JavaScript files that it needs.

To fix this error, you need to add the following dependency to the `wp_enqueue_script()` call:

`wp_enqueue_script('Turbo', 'https://unpkg.com/@hotwired/turbo@7.3.0/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js', array('jquery'), '7.3.0', false)`;

The jquery dependency is required by the Turbo script. Once you have added this dependency, the error should go away.

Here is the complete code that you need to load the Turbo script in WordPress:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('Turbo', 'https://unpkg.com/@hotwired/turbo@7.3.0/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js', array('jquery'), '7.3.0', false);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```